# opening other URL in php in order to print it while user sees sth completelly else (printing in background)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Maybe you can help me in this.

I have a welcome screen that say "enter the code". User enters is, and he gets message (another page) saying "please wait". On this level the system is checking if the code is valid. Here starts the problem.

Code goes to completelly different page with php script. The script returns answear and if the code is ok it displays the result that should be printed (for example proper chart). BUT the user should not see this chart on the screen. He only should see "please wait" page, and then "your stuff was printed" page or "sorry chart is not ready yet, or the code is wrong" page...

So basicly not only pages should have some kind of communication, but also invisible URL print in the background should be started.

For the moment I have no idea how to solve this using php/javascript/ajax and what is avaiable for web.

I would really appreciate help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: why on earth would you want to prevent users seeing what they are going to print on their own printers???

Comment: It's not their printer for one :) but mostly becouse what is printed is not html and users don't have acces to link or back button in the browser. Whole app is webpage, but it doesnt look like one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick hack to do this would be to use something like [jQuery-printPage](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-printPage-plugin).

```
$(".btnPrint").printPage({
  url: "/print/custompage/html",
  attr: "href",
  message:"Your document is being created"
})
```

Comment: Ha! I didn't know sth like this exist. Instant+1. I will try this for sure. So all left now is to figure out how to create comunication between the pages, but I was thinking that maybe it doesn't have to be at the same time. Maybe first I can check the code, and then decide to print/or on to print. Thanx.

Comment: I tested it, works just fine. Small problem: plugin is based on link, and link has to be autotriggered (in this case) so I used: $(".btnPrint").trigger("click"); and worker ok.

Comment: Use print.always_print_silent in Firefox config (about:config) in order to trigger browser silent printing (no print prompt).